# Warn towards use of more efficient function in subclass

Tags: scala, inheritance, warnings, software-design

I want to implement a scala library for graphs. This library should also contain different types of trees.

1 the class tree extends the class graph

2 the class graph has a method getAllPrecursors(Node n) which returns all the Nodes fron which you can reach n.

3 the class tree has the method getParent(Node n) which returns the parent of the Node n (as an option, None marking the root)

Now, if someone calls the method "getAllPrecursors" for a tree I want to display a warning like " trees have at most 1 precursor, use getParent instead".

Is there any way to do this? Is there any better way of building this library? Should Trees not be a subclass of graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't worry about performance unless you can prove that the performance of this code is significant to overall performance: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil"

However you can do what you want by overloading `getAllPrecursors` and marking it deprecated:

```
class graph {
  def getAllPrecursors(n: Node): List[Node] = ...
}

class tree extends graph {
  def getParent(n: Node) = ...

  @deprecated("Use getParent rather that getAllPrecursors", "1.0")
  override def getAllPrecursors(n: Node) = List(getParent(n))
}
```

This will give a deprecation warning if you use `getAllPrecursors` on a value of type `tree` but not on a value of type `graph` (even if that value is actually an instance of `tree`)

As far as the design goes, it would be better to have `getAllPrecursors` and `getParent` as methods on `Node` (and `TreeNode`) rather than on the graph itself.

Comment: The question was more design oriented. Performance is fine, but getting a list of precursors seems unnecesary. Wouldn't @deprecated be misleading, since the method is not deprecated but rather unnecesary?